# how to get Lat Long of an Address using arcGis JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Hi how can I get the Latitude and Longitude using arcgis Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

for the 3.x api would look like this

```
require(["esri/map"], function(Map) {
  var map = new Map("mapDiv"),
  map.on("click", myClickHandler);

  function myClickHandler(evt) {
    console.log(evt)
  }
});
```

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/inside_events.html

For the 2.x api would look like this:

```
dojo.connect(map, "onClick", mapClick);
function mapClick(evt){
     console.log(evt.mapPoint)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the x & y coordinates from Map, the Answer provided by Aiden works.

If you need to get a location from an Address information. you would need to use GeocodeServer service to get the location. You could create and host your own service or use the one of the service hosted by ESRI.

http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Locators/

```
require(["esri/tasks/locator", ... 
], function(Locator, ... ) {
    var locator = new Locator("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Locators/ESRI_Geocode_USA/GeocodeServer");
    var address = {"Single Line Input": "100 main street"};
    var params = {address: address, searchExtent: map.extent};              
    locator.outSpatialReference= map.spatialReference;
    locator.addressToLocations(params).then(function(addressCandidates){
        ....
    });
});
```

Details about the Locator task can be found at below location.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/locator-amd.html#locator1